# What does mean that ListView.builder creates widgets on demand?

Tags: flutter, dart

From [flutter's official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html):

> ListView.builder creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets that are created on demand.
>   This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible.

I was doing some experiment to see how it works and to understand if it really creates only the widgets that are actually visible.

I wrote this simple code:

```
List<int> numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

void test(){
  print("one widget created"+DateTime.now().toString());
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 300,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index){
        test();
        return Card(
          Text("number "+numbers[index].toString())
        );
}
```

Now in theory if the maximum quantity of Cards visible on the screen is 3, in the console I should read just 3 messages but if I execute the code, I will see 9 messages in the console, it means that the function was executed 9 times and not 3 as expected.
So, what does mean that the widgets are created on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct here that the `ListView.builder` will not create 3 but 9 elements as it keeps some buffer at the top and bottom of the screen so as to maintain the fps. Suppose it created only 3 items and the user scrolls the with high speed **then the scrolling would lag as Flutter will need to create the displaying the items first and then render it** so to avoid these type scenarios it keeps some amount of buffer already. It creates Widgets on demand that's true, let's take an example if there are 1000 items that needs to be displayed and only 3 can be displayed at a time so its not like that Flutter will create 1000 objects of widget rather as you stated above it creates only 9 and as the user scrolls it will destroy and create new ones.

Comment: I've just done another experiment and you are right, I think the equation that flutter uses is (x=y*4) where x is the value of the total widgets to load and y is the value of the visible elements. But there is a detail, unfortunately, flutter does not destroy the elements that are not more visible but simply loads other elements, in fact in my experiment, I have created a list of 66 elements and after I have scrolled it up and down, the app had started to lag a little

Comment: Ohh I wasn't aware of the equation, but yes that's how ListView.builder works. Glad I could help!

Comment: Note that this "extra buffer" can be configured with `cacheExtent` (default is 250.0). Set this to 0 and your list will only build the items in view.

Answer (score 1):

ListView *does* create widgets on demand. It's just that your vision of "on-demand" is slightly different from theirs.

ListView will create all widgets from index 0 up to the point where the user scrolled *and stop there*.

So if we have a list of 1000 items, and the user scrolled to the 50 item and 3 items are visible, then `ListView.builder` will build the first 53 widgets (+ potentially a few extra for a smooth scrolling).

So it does not build *only what's visible*, but it doesn't *build everything* either.

Comment: Do all 53 widgets remain in memory at that point? Or is there something like Android's RecylerView which recycles views which aren't immediately visible?

Comment: All the 53 stays in memory, until you need fewer than that. They are needed because they can potentially be animated, so what's visible may change over time